# Ticks64() returning 0 on FMX (Android)

Tags: android, firemonkey, indy

when running the Ticks64() function (defined in IdGlobal.pas) in Firemonkey on Android, I get 0 as result.  Anyone else seen this?

Comment: What you suggest implies that the Posix [`clock_gettime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) function (which is what `Ticks64()` calls on Android) is populating the output `timespec` record with all 0s, possibly if the function is failing (which Indy does not currently check). Can you verify?

Comment: I retried this today, and I'm getting a valid UInt64 now.  I don't know what happened, maybe I made a mistake when I tested...